# Is there any open-source front-end for modified Gnosis Safe smart-contracts?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I modified some of the smart-contracts designed by Gnosis team, just changed some logic, leaving all the functions unchanged. Now I want to try to plug them to front-end. Apparently, standard Gnosis front-end is not suitable for that since their infrastructure is not supporting modified contracts, so I'm wondering if there are some front-ends which are capable of working with custom safe contracts.

Answer (score 0):

There are no other official front-ends apart from the ones listed on Github

Comment: That's exactly the point, I'm wondering if there's any other third-party ones with the same methods of interaction with the smart-contracts. I've read the docs Gnosis provided, they have a list of third-party front-ends, but I found them unsuitable for my task.